# how to get list of RDS names by passing vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-aurora

I am looking to get the list of all RDS cluster names when i pass a "vpc-id" as input. I can only see the function "describe_vpcs" available. Any other function available to fulfil my requirement? please advise

Comment: That's not a supported filter so you will need to pull all the instances via `describe-db-clusters` and filter on the client side. An RDS cluster isn't directly linked to a VPC. It's attached a RDS subnet which points to a VPC subnet which belongs to a VPC

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('rds')

vpc_id = input('vpc-id: ')
response = client.describe_db_instances()
for instance in response['DBInstances']:
    VPC_ID = instance['DBSubnetGroup']['VpcId']
    DBId = instance['DBInstanceIdentifier']
    if vpc_id == VPC_ID:
        print(DBId)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).